Specflow Scenario with Tag-Based JSON Data Management
My specflow scenario has 4 tags example @sanity-qa, @Regression-qa, @Sanity-Stg and @regression-Stg. Scenario example is below:
   @sanity-qa
   @Regression-qa
   @Sanity-Stg
   @regression-Stg
Scenario: Search for term and validate result
    Given user opens amazon.com
    When user searches for a term
    Then user saves the first result in a tag-specific JSON file
    Then user searches for the first result in the search field
    Then user confirms that the first result appears in the JSON file

Test is executed from command line: dotnet  test --filter "Testcategory=sanity-qa"
Jsonfile is created based on the tag, in the above scenario it is sanityqa.json by reading scenriocontext.ScenarioInfo.Tags.
Key and value will be SanitySearchterm: Firstsearchresulttitle
I believe the issue is my approach and running the test from command line. Is there a way to fix it? I tried reading the current scenariotag from BeforeScenario but it always prints the first tag no matter if I run regression-Stg.
Approach: I read the scenario tag, if the tag contains sanity-qa, jsonFile to read is sanityqa.json and return jsonfile and break the loop. else if the tag contains regression-qa jsonfile to read is regressionqa.json, return jsonfile and break the loop.
My expectation - since I specify which tag I need to run in the commandline, it should look for the specified tag and read the appropriate jsonfile
Issue is when I read back from json file - it always read the json file for the first tag even if I run for the second tag.

Please close this query. I was able to resolve it by using Examples

@Sanity-qa
Examples:
|Json|
|sanityqa.json|

Please [edit] your question to respond to comments asking for clarification.
